# Python:Replace tab in double quotes

Tags: python, regex, replace

Hi i have line where i want to replace tab in double quotes. I have wrote script for that but it is not working as I want.
My line:

```
Q3U962  Mus musculus    MRMP-mouse  Optimization    "MRMP-mouse "
```

My script:

```
    for repline in reppepdata:
    findtorep=re.findall(r"['\"](.*?)['\"]", repline)
    if len(findtorep) >0:
        for repitem in findtorep:
            repchar =repitem
            repchar=repchar.replace('\t', '')
```

My output should be:

```
Q3U962  Mus musculus    MRMP-mouse  Optimization    "MRMP-mouse"
```

But I am getting like this:

```
Q3U962  Mus musculus    MRMP-mouseOptimization  "MRMP-mouse"
```

Words are separated by tab delimiter here.

```
Q3U962\tMus musculus\tMRMP-mouse\tOptimization \t"MRMP-mouse\t"
```

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you string have escaped quotes or any escape sequences? If there can be no escape sequences, the answer is clear.

Comment: Just a guess - try: r'\t' ?

Comment: @simplynail it is not working

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry what do you mean by escaped quotes ?

Comment: Can your (literal) input look like `Q3U962  Mus\\ musculus\"    MRMP-mouseOptimization  "MRMP-    \"mouse\""` (where ``\\`` stands for a literal backslash, and `\"` stands for a quote inside a field)? Or, maybe a  `""`  that can stand for a literal `"`?

Comment: Ok, see http://ideone.com/7kfJf1 and let know if it is working for you.

Comment: You say *Replace tab in double quotes*, and the regex you used actually can match single-quoted substrings. So, what is true? well, `r"['\"](.*?)['\"]"` will match `'string"` and `"string'` like texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your above solution is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: This answer assumes (it is [confirmed by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576959/pythonreplace-tab-in-double-quotes/38577234#comment64543584_38576959)) that there are no escaped quotes/sequences in the input.

You may match the quoted string with a simple `"[^"]+"` regex that matches a `"`, 1+ chars other than `"` and a `"`, and replace the tabs inside within a lambda:

```
import re
s = 'Q3U96  Mus musculu MRMP-mous   Optimizatio "MRMP-mouse "'
res = re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace("\t", ""), s)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/7kfJf1)